# PsExec run remote batch file in visible mode

Tags: psexec

I am trying to execute following command

```
psexec \\x.x.x.x -d -c -f cmd.exe /c d:\test\hello.bat
```

It runs fine and gives output

```
cmd.exe started on x.x.x.x with process ID 106084.
```

But when I login on x.x.x.x I can find the process ID but no visible batch file is launched. It runs in background.

Batch file

```
echo "Hello"
pause
```

Please tell me how to see the command window launched on x.x.x.x

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the command line switches, there is one for interactive mode.

Comment: I did add -i switch but if I issue command from machine A for machine B then machine A stops for execution on machine B to complete but when I log in on machine B I can only see the process ID from task manager but no visible cmd window.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can look at the Session Id for your current user and pass it as parameter with `-i` For example:

```
PsExec.exe -s -d -i 2 c:\temp\MyServer MyConsoleApp.exe
```

To look at the current Session Id you can run `query session`

Sometimes the Session Id is 2 for the active user you want to start process for, so try looking for your correct Session Id and use it with `-i` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of those:

1. ```
   psexec \\server -u xxx-p xxxx /accepteula  -i 1 -d cmd.exe /K "cd d:\test && call hello.bat"
   ```
2. ```
   psexec \\server -u xxx -p xxxx /accepteula  -i 1 -d d:\test\hello.bat
   ```

Comment: Hi Philip, can you please check this I am not able to launch GUI as you said above.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24203577/launch-notepad-exe-using-psexec-sysinternal-tool

Answer (score 1):

Alex K. is correct. Specifically, remove the "-d", which tells PsExec "Don't wait for process to terminate (non-interactive)". In fact, if you run the sample batch file above, which includes "pause", the cmd process will continue to run on the remote host (invisible to the remote host's GUI, since it's done via PSExec) until you kill that process.

Answer (score 0):

```
PsExec.exe -s -i 2 C:\path_to_exe.exe
```

This need to check with the session ID variable (-s & -i)