# How can you bring a background process to the foreground (make it possible to select the GUI)

Tags: psexec

I have written a small script to access a remote machine then run an executable however the executable runs only in the background.

Is it possible to run so I am able to see the gui?

```
psexec IPADDRESS -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -i SESSIONID -d "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
```

Comment: FYI: Including your code will help get an answer :)

Comment: Thanks James C, added

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566862/psexec-run-remote-batch-file-in-visible-mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help Avshalom.

The answer for me was to change my sessionid from 0 to 2.