# In Windows, can NT Authority/System run a powershell script as another user

Tags: windows, powershell

I am running a powershell script remotely via an agent. The agent on the machine runs the powershell script as "NT Authority/SYSTEM" but I want to the switch to another user on the system and run the powershell script.

Below is the code that I used to switch to "Administrator" account but I am getting permission denied error .

```
$username = "domainname\administrator"
$pw = "XXXXXXXX"
$password = $pw | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$password
Start-Process Powershell.exe -Credential $cred  -ArgumentList '-noexit','-File', ' C:\Users\Administrator\test.ps1'

Below is the error I am getting. 
 Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied.
```

Comment: Why do you need to run the script as some other user?

Comment: I am trying to do read and write excel operation via powershellscript remotely on the system.  When I run my powershell script it run as NT authority/System and excel starts with Sign-In prompt. I trying to avoid this sign-in by switching to existing user on the system.

Comment: What are you trying to do with Excel?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue while trying to launch a powershell script on my Windows 10 guest from a Linux host, through qemu-guest-agent.

Part of what my script did was launching a desktop software and interacting with its gui.

My problem was solved using PsExec.

My agent command :

```
virsh -c qemu:///system qemu-agent-command my_domain \
'{"execute": "guest-exec", "arguments": { "path": "cmd.exe", "arg": [ "/c", "c:\\path\\to\\my_psexec_script.cmd" ], "capture-output": true }}'
```

My PsExec script, in the cmd file :

```
C:\path\to\PsExec.exe -accepteula \\DESKTOP-NAME -u user -p password -i sessionid powershell.exe -File C:\path\to\powershell_script.ps1
```

This is not a secure solution since the password is stored within the script.

To get the session id of the user of your choice, use the following command :

```
query session
```

The reason I used an intermediary script to launch PsExec was simply because it was easier to do so on my guest rather than entering all the arguments from my agent.

I based my solution on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566862/psexec-run-remote-batch-file-in-visible-mode)

It was also important that my script executed in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Try using invoke-command like below

```
$remoteSession=New-PSSession RemoteComputername -credential $credential1
Invoke-Command -session $remoteSession -scriptblock {
$newcredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("domain\myuser", (ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force))
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $newcredential ArgumentList '-noexit','-File', ' C:\Users\Administrator\test.ps1'
}
```

**References:**
https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/powershell_remoting-24/14483/runas-a-different-user-on-a-remote-server

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ConvertTo-SecureString does not work with variables with "The system cannot find the path specified" error.
In my case that happened, when I tried to execute my script under "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM".
And saving password in a script is not a good idea :)
I would suggest to execute in PowerShell:

```
ConvertTo-SecureString "your-password" -AsPlainText -Force|ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

The result will look like (I replaced with dots portion of it):

```
01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00...476ee5cd27619ce72296a774f1400000091265bae2a7d2851f8807a9a9d70a7a6a7e6dc91
```

After that in your script:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00...476ee5cd27619ce72296a774f1400000091265bae2a7d2851f8807a9a9d70a7a6a7e6dc91"
```

Hope this will help